# MAMP Error: checking MySQL databases failed

Tags: mysql, mamp

I recently reset the password from the root user in MySQL to a blank value. I verified in the config.inc.php file that this was the case:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
```

However, every time I restart the MAMP servers, this error pops up:

> **Checking the MySQL databases failed**
>
> Error message:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying
>   to connect

However, I can still connect to my MySQL database perfectly fine through MySQLWorkBench. It's just that this silly error pops up every time, even though I don't have a password set. Why does this keep happening?

I've tried everything from restarting MAMP to resetting my password from the command line ([the solution in the MAMP docs](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#q9)), to no avail. I also tried executing the following:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. 
...
mysql>
```

So I can successfully connect to MySQL through the terminal. Does this mean that the problem is in my phpMyAdmin configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of mamp files that have a hard coded value for the root password in `/Applications/MAMP/bin` such as `checkMysql.sh`.

You would need to change these files as well.

Because you've reset it to an empty string, you will have to change the `-proot` to `--password=`, otherwise you could have used `-pNEWPASS`.

The full list of files is `checkMysql.sh`, `quickCheckMysqlUpgrade.sh`, `stopMysql.sh` and `upgradeMysql.sh` that I can see.